# How to make the entityid of <chatter:feedWithFollowers /> point to the current user logged in?

Tags: visualforce, chatter

I'm creating a visualforce page with standard features like chatter and I'm also adding a list of cases on that page which points to a case view. I want the entityid for "chatter:feedWithFollowers" to get the id of the user that is logged in. Is that possible? If so, how would I go about doing that? Thanks!

`<chatter:feedWithFollowers entityId="{IDHERE}"/>
<apex:enhancedlist type="Case" height="730" customizable="false" rowsPerPage="25" Listid="00BQ00000023TG7" />`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Global Variable `$User.Id`:

```
<chatter:feedWithFollowers entityId="{!$User.Id}"/>
```

If you want to replicate the Chatter 'News Feed' that a user gets in their Chatter stream, which includes User news items as well as updates on records that the User is following, you probably want to use the `<chatter:newsFeed/>` component instead.

Comment: Yep! Be sure to accept the answer if it solved your problem, and vote it up (if you have enough reputation). Also as I mentioned in an edit, you might want to consider the `<chatter:newsFeed>` component as well

Comment: I am trying to replicate the Salesforce home page basically with some custom components. so the <chatter:feedWithFollowers should do that right?

Comment: I tried to upvote, don't have the rep yet. And will only let me accept the answer after 9 minutes, so will do that after.

Comment: @user988 Yes if that's what you're trying to replicate, I'd use `<chatter:newsFeed/>`